# how can I make an for-loop work with a variable inside a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, global-variables

first of all, HEY!, I've already asked twice here and both got good answuers that helped a lot.

So... I want to my for-loop print on the console log all my variables on `commands` variable.

I would like to print only `BOH`, `HALO` and `BOOM HSAKALAKA` variables, not their texts: `BOH!`, `HALO!`, `BOOM SHAKALAKA!`.

```
var commands = {
'BOH': {text: 'BOH!'},
'HALO': {text: 'HALO!'},
'BOOM SHAKALAKA': {text: 'BOOM SHAKALAKA!'},
};

for (number = 0; number < commands.lenght; number++){
    console.log(commands[number]);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z64bZ/3/) ?

```
var commands = {
'BOH)': {text: 'BOH!'},
'HALO': {text: 'HALO!'},
'BOOM SHAKALAKA': {text: 'BOOM SHAKALAKA!'},
};

for(key in commands){

if(commands.hasOwnProperty(key)){ //get only the properties of the current object and skip inherited properties 

    console.log("variable - " + key + " " + "value - " + commands[key].text);

}

};
```

In your example, you are looping through an array that doesn't exist. `commands` is not an array, it's an object. So, in order to loop through an object we should use its `key` property.

In our case `key` is `'BOH)'` and the value of that `key` is `commands[key]` => `BOH!`.

Comment: I think that's the answer... well not, I want to print the first string on the variable, for example: I want to print `BOH)`, `HALO` and `BOOM SHAKALAKA`. not the texts.

Comment: so I only have to put inside for `key in commands` and it will print all of them. thx mate, helped me a lot( I would vote you but I only have 12 rep TT)

Comment: BTW, you can vote my answer up, whenever you have enough reputation ;)